# How to pass data dynamically from angular 6 typescript to animateTransform "from" attribute?

Tags: svg, angular6, animatetransform

I've tried several ways, below are my attempts:

In my typescript file, I set the value as:

```
this.value = "130"; //for first method
this.rotation = "130 192 190"; //for second method
```

While in component.html

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                  type="rotate"
                  from="{{value}} 192 190"
                  to="0 192 190"
                  dur="3s"></animateTransform>
```

second method:

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                  type="rotate"
                  [attr.from]="rotation"
                  to="0 192 190"
                  dur="3s"></animateTransform>
```

both methods arent working. Any way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `[from]="rotation"` ?

Comment: i just tried, and i got an error as below:

"Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'from' since it isn't a known property of ':svg:animateTransform'" @FabianN.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just take the good parts of both:

```
this.value = "130"
```

With

```
<animateTransform attributeName="transform"
                  type="rotate"
                  [attr.from]="value + ' 192 190'"
                  to="0 192 190"
                  dur="3s"></animateTransform>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I modify the part [from] to [attr.from] and it works like charm! thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I edited it into the answer. I'm just confused why the type definitions for `svg:animateTransform` seem to be missing, this should work without one having to use `attr.` Also isn't that now just the same as your second method?